# Can I pass method to observable as result handler in angular?

Tags: angular

So I have following piece of code:

```
someService.doSomething().subscribe(result=>{
   this.handleMyResult(result)
}
```

And I would like to do something like that:

```
someService.doSomething().subscribe(this.handleMyResult);
```

This does not work in 100%. I think that I might have some sytax issue here, as `handleMyResult` gets called indeed, but argument passed in is `undefined`

Is it possible to make it work??

Comment: You said it's the argument being passed in that's undefined, but did you mean to say it was the value of `this` that's undefined? If so, have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) to better understand `this` and then [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to better understand why arrow functions "fix" this.

Comment: Its good to know that it is called "arrow functions" - didnt know that. Why does it work I can imagine cuz of my knowledge of lambads and anonymous classes in java (altough there is no `this` context in it) and closures in php

Comment: And what makes me curious is why question is getting downvoted while correct answer to it gets possitive feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
someService.doSomething().subscribe(this.handleMyResult);
```

and result is passed in, but to use the `this` component scope within the `this.handleMyResult` method you must bind it.

```
someService.doSomething().subscribe(this.handleMyResult.bind(this));
```

Comment: Ok I understand, so it wont make my code more beautifull. Indeed that works like expected. Thanks! Ill accept in 5 minutes

Comment: So `this.handleMyResults` equals to `MyClass.prototype.applyNewShipmentData` ahh that nasty javascript :)